# When do variance of MLE and variance of posterior match?

Tags: variance, maximum-likelihood, posterior

Assuming a Gaussian likelihood, $y \mid x, w \sim \mathcal{N}(w^\top x, \sigma^2)$, the variance of the least squares estimate $\hat{w} = \mathrm{argmax}_w p(y \mid X, w)$ is $\mathbb{V}[\hat{w} \mid X, y] = \sigma^2(X^\top X)^{-1}$.

On the other hand, the distribution $p(w \mid X, y) \propto p(y \mid X, w)$ (the "posterior" distribution without a prior) is Gaussian since $$
\log p(w \mid X, y) = -\frac{1}{2} \left[\sigma^{-2} w^\top X^\top X w - 2 \sigma^{-2} y^\top X w\right] + \mathrm{const}.
$$
The variance of this Gaussian is precisely $\mathbb{V}[w \mid X, y] = \sigma^2(X^\top X)^{-1}$ which is the same as the variance of the least squares estimate.

I am wondering if the two variances match because the likelihood is linear / Gaussian / some other reason, or if it is a more general property of the MLE that its variance matches the variance of the "posterior" distribution.

Comment: What you refer to as "without a prior" is impossible, as the posterior is a function of likelihood and prior. What may give you such results is when you have a "flat" prior $p(w)\propto1$.

Comment: @ChristophHanck yes this is what i meant to say :)